# convert character variable to time in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a variable called post_time which is of character type

```
Type     : Character
Length   :  5 
Foramt   : $5. 
Informat : $5.
```

eg: 00300 ,01250

How do I get time from this? can someone pls help me out?
need the time to look like 03:00AM 12:50PM 
Need to display all the time in standard time zone

Comment: Rather depends on what's stored in it, doesn't it?

Comment: What time value should 00300 correspond to, 3AM?

Comment: it should be shown as 03:00AM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SAS will work directly with this via the HHMMSS informat.

```
data _null_;
  x = input('02100',HHMMSS5.);
  put x= timeampm9.;
run;
```

Any time zone concerns can be handled using either a time zone sensitive format, such as NLDATMTZ., and/or the TZONES2U or TZONEU2S functions, which work with DATETIME but may be able to work with your time values if you never go across a date boundary (though using timezones that's risky).

See the [SAS Documentation page on Timezones](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/nlsref/67399/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0px72paaaqx06n1ozps024j78cl.htm) for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the first three digits are hours and last two are minutes this may work:

```
data have;
input time $;
cards;
00300
00400
00234
;
run;

data want;
    set have;
    time_var=hms(
                input(substr(time, 1,3), 3.),
                input(substr(time, 4,2), 2.), 
                0);
    format time_var timeampm8.;
run;
```

Comment: is there a syntax error? 

I am getting a error saying  ERROR : Found"," when expecting )

Comment: Worked on my computer, SAS 9.3. Did it work on yours?

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! It worked for me. However I further need to convert it into IST timezone. It is in STD timezone right now. Can you pls help me out?

Comment: Timezone would be handled in the format or with the TZONESxx functions.  http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/nlsref/67399/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0px72paaaqx06n1ozps024j78cl.htm